# Having problems when I want to implement the Spinner function in Tab fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I have 3 tab fragments name Tab1Settings, Tab2Scanner and Tab3Receipts. And 1 main activity called TabbedActvity. I want to use the Spinner function, but I'm not too enter code here sure where to put it as I have put both in Tab1Settings(the place where I put my spinner at) and TabbedActivity but both still resulted in having errors.

```
package mapp.com.sg.receiptscanner;
```

/**
 * Created by USER on 5/8/2017.
 */

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import static mapp.com.sg.receiptscanner.R.layout.tab1settings;




public class Tab1Settings extends Fragment {
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(tab1settings, container, false);
    Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById();


    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Tab1Settings.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.dropdown));
    myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mySpinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);



    return rootView;



}


}
```

Comment: I am assuming you want spinner in the toolbar or actionbar?

Comment: Nope, I want in on the page itself.